# Post method of CFHTTP is not working in coldfusion 10 however get works

Tags: post, coldfusion, get, coldfusion-10

I have a page in Coldfusion 10 which uses the  below code :

```
<cfhttp url ="http://mysite.am.com/index.cfm" resolveURL="yes"  throwOnError="no" method="post">
<cfhttpparam type ="formfield" name="fuseaction" value="searchOrders">
<cfhttpparam type ="formfield" name="cookieValue" value="#cookie.Mycookie#">
</cfhttp>
<cfoutput>left(trim(#cfhttp.filecontent#),4)</cfoutput>
```

second called page has below code:

```
<form>
<cfif isDefined("attributes.cookieValue")>
TRUE
<cfelse>
FALSE
</cfif>
</form>
```

Nothing is returned on the calling page. However if I pass the url (http://mysite.am.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=searchOrders&Mycookie=C176060) directly in the browser it works and displays TRUE. There is no error on the page. The page has nothing returned.

Comment: You say nothing is returned? How about `<Cfdump var="#cfhttp#"/>` do you get any status codes? any content outside those first 4 characters?

Comment: Is there anything in mysite.am.com/index.cfm that processes form variables?

Comment: @DanBracuk - I believe he's using a fusebox application. It translates both form and URL vars into the "attributes" scope.

Comment: Try to cfdump cfhttp variable as Mark said. Your code is working on my local machine on same setup and @MarkAKruger, Not relevant to the question or your answer but OP is a girl.

Comment: sorry... my bad. I was careless with my review :)

Comment: Do a traditional #cfhttp.filecontent# (without cfdump), and give the called page this content `<cfdump label="attributes" var="#attributes#"><br><br><br><br><cfdump label="form" var="#form#">`

Comment: Which web server are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I'd debug this by checking the Browser's Network (Chrome Developer Toolbar / Firebug) to see if your CFHTTP is posting correctly and what it's posting and see what the response is. Also instead of using the **attributes** scope maybe just use **form** scope to see if it's coming through.

Sorry, not enough rep to post a comment :(

Comment: Up'd to help him/her get his two points for comment privileges. Also, I agree (and previously posted) that doing dumps on the target page is probably a useful step to debugging this. Dumping is a handy/easy way to debug cfhttp calls / web service invocations.

Answer (score 0):

In the second page you should access through 'FORM' scope. You have given 'FORMFIELD' in the first page.
Don't use attribute scope for fetching variables.

Comment: In Fusebox (the framework she's using) the Form & Url scope are mashed into the Attributes scope to make it easier to handle variables. I can't find the direct reference to the official documentation but here's a [good blog post](http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/2008/05/30/dealing-with-form-and-url-variables/) that explains it with examples. But I guess it's user preference which way you do it, no right or wrong answer